# count vs all.count in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Newbie to mongoid on rails.

What is the performance impact of using

```
Class.all.count
```

vs

```
Class.count
```

in mongoid? Both have the class of Mongoid::Criteria, so what is the point of using Class.all?

Answer (score 1):

`Model.count` and `Model.all.count` are equivalent with Mongoid. If you track the queries, you'll see things like:

```
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=... command={:count=>"models", :query=>{}} runtime: ...
```

for both. The `all` method doesn't do anything terribly useful with Mongoid: if you have a query already (i.e. a `Mongoid::Criteria`) then `query` and `query.all` are functionally equivalent; if you just have a model class then `Model.all` is just a `Mongoid::Criteria` that matches all documents.